# Is it possible to reject a landing after the thrust reversers have been deployed?

Tags: landing, thrust-reverser

Since thrust reversers take time to deploy and stow are you committed to the landing once you engage them?

Comment: Related: [When a large commercial jet touches down, is it committed to stopping?](//aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15369)

Comment: No because once thrust reversers are deployed it is nearly possibly and risky to takeoff again. Not enough speed even to takeoff deploying and un deploying the thrust reversers. Especially for big airliners like the 747 or a380(Impossible to get those planes up in the air again after thrust reversers are deployed ) so your answer is no too risky.

Comment: I'm not sure this is completely correct.  I'm being somewhat pedantic here, but if you have a long enough runway, there is no reason you could not retract the thrust reversers, increase power, and accelerate back to rotation speed and take off again.  That said, it's extremely unlikely that you'd ever have both enough runway to do this AND the motivation to actually do it under normal commercial operations... .  But that does not mean it's impossible.

Comment: @ljwobker Please read the linked question.  The problem is not how much runway remains.  The danger is with asymmetric stowage.